# Oracle - Search in all tables with data only in all columns

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

i',m trying to find in all tables with data in all columns..

example

EMPLOYEE table with ID = 123

```
COLUMNS         DATA
ID              1
NAME            TEST
ADDRESS         TESTADDRESS
PHONE             
EMAIL         
POSITION        DEV
```

The output will be ID, NAME, ADDRESS, and POSITION.. so basically all columns with data only..

by the way, i can't rely on NUM_DISTINCT in USER_TAB_COLUMNS..

Comment: That row doesn't have data in all columns, so the table doesn't. I'm not at all sure what you are trying to do. Are you trying to list the column names in that table that have data for that ID, or for any IDs? Or in 'all tables' - which is what, all tables in a schema? And based on specific keys again? Or something else?

Comment: A bit confused on what you are asking for, you mention search but focus on display in the question.    Seems like you may have two questions here you are you trying to combine.

Answer (score 0):

You could gather statistics for your tables and check `NUM_NULLS` column in `DBA_TAB_COL_STATISTICS`. Everything is described in [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96533/stats.htm).

If for some reason You cannot do it then use something like this simple PL/SQL block:

```
declare 
    v_nulls number;
    v_sql varchar(4000);
begin 
    for t in (select table_name from user_tables order by table_name) 
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line('====== Table: '||t.table_name);
        for c in (select column_name 
                    from user_tab_cols 
                    where table_name = t.table_name order by column_name) 
        loop
            v_sql := 'select count(case when '||c.column_name||' is null then 1 end) '
                     ||'  from '||t.table_name;

            execute immediate v_sql into v_nulls;

            if v_nulls = 0 then
                dbms_output.put_line(rpad(c.column_name, 30)||' - no nulls found');
            else
                dbms_output.put_line(rpad(c.column_name, 30)||' - contains null values');
            end if;
        end loop;
    end loop;
end;
```

Sample output:

```
====== Table: CARS
CID                            - no nulls found
MODEL                          - contains null values
PID                            - contains null values
====== Table: PEOPLE
NAME                           - no nulls found
PID                            - no nulls found
```

We are counting nulls for each column in each table in your schema, so this can be slow. Gathering statistics is the proper way to do such things.

If, for instance, You need info about columns in tables `Employee` and `Courses` add proper `where clause` in first loop.

```
select table_name from user_tables where table_name in ('Employee', 'Courses')
```